# Android Market links on non Android browsers

Tags: android, http-status-code-404, hyperlink, marketplace

Android Market links go to 404 on non Android browsers. When will Google fix this?

It's really annoying having to check the user-agent and displaying something else for non Android browsers.

Comment: Not really a stackoverflow question but I agree.

Comment: By non-Android browsers do you mean non-native browsers installed on an Android device or browsers outside of the Android devices, eg. Firefox on a PC or Safari on a Mac?

Comment: google fixed this with the new market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the market:// syntax anymore.  You can use http://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.abc and it will be picked up by the Market app if on the phone, or if not supported (pc, no Market installed) sent to the Market website.